# HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseFeature>().ReasonPhrase is not working in .net core 2.1?

Tags: c#, .net-core

We are using below code to send the custom message from server side to client side in http request. It working properly in .net core 2.0.

```
Response.HttpContext.Features.Get().ReasonPhrase = 'File already exists';
```

While using the same code in .net core 2.1 it does not works. It doesn't throw any script errors but we couldn't get message in client side success.

How to resolve this problem? Please suggest your ideas.

Comment: This is server-side code, not a script. If that code fails it will throw an exception. The *client* will only receive a 500 error, as it should. Are there any erros logged on the server? What do they say? Is logging configured in the first place? Is there a try/catch block that logs exceptions?

Comment: BTW if you want to return anything to the client, all tutorials show using a method like `OK(something)`, returning a data object or an ActionResult with the desired status, reason and possible body. The HttpContext is never used, either in the older ASP.NET MVC or the newer .NET Core frameworks.

Comment: No @PanagiotisKanavos, This is also the solution in .net core. But if fails in version specific

Comment: Don't post duplicate questions.